# Java text standardization between inverted commas - error

Tags: java, regex

Please, I spent few days trying to understand java behavior and mainly, trying to solve the following case:

We have the following scenario:

```
I|123|"hi"
U|321|"ola"
D|098|"welcome \n to the hotel \n california"
I|234|"ya!"
```

As an ultimate result, I need to replace all \n between "" but, honestly I gave up carry it out in "one-shot" because we can have different patterns and, sometimes, we can find " (inverted commas) inside inverted commas"... like this `" welcome \n to the \"hotel\" \n California".`

To carry it out easy and, theory, fast I have decided to create a process where split the final results into steps:

```
1 - Replace all break lines with special notation;
2 - Replace all remaining break lines with space "";
3 - Replace the special notation, previously inserted, by the original break line! ;
```

Something like that:

**Input**

```
D|098|"welcome \n to the Hotel \n California"
I|234|"ya!"
```

**Steps:**

```
(Replacing main brake line for special notation)
1 - D|098|"welcome \n to the hotel \california"_¥I|234|"ya!"

(Replacing all brake lines)
2 - D|098|"welcome to the Hotel California"_¥I|234|"ya!"

(Replacing special n)
3 - D|098|"welcome to the Hotel California"
    I|234|"ya!"
```

**The problem**

I'm using java with AWS CLI to bring and treat the files, in memory, and then put it on the file system! Throughout the process, some treatments are performed one of those, date standardization, using the same technics that, for now, won't work in this case.

To make it, I'm using the following code:

myString.replaceAll("^\n[I|U|D]", "_¥").replaceAll("\n+"," ").replaceAll("_¥","\n");

In the context previously wrote:

```
 _¥|123|"hi"
 U|321|"ola"
 D|098|"welcome \n to the hotel \n california"
 I|234|"ya!"
```

After applying this solution, all file content contacts in one line. All line became once!

I really appreciate any help! "what is my fault" in this case!

Regards! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `^` start of string anchor in the first regex, and either capture the letter matched after `\n` and use `$1` in the replacement pattern to "restore" the char in the result, or use a lookahead in the pattern that would not consume the `I`, `U` or `D` char on the next line:

```java
.replaceAll("\n([IUD])", "_¥$1").replaceAll("\n+"," ").replaceAll("_¥","\n")
.replaceAll("\n(?=[IUD])", "_¥").replaceAll("\n+"," ").replaceAll("_¥","\n")
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/6gUWmG):

```java
String s = "I|123|\"hi\"\nU|321|\"ola\"\nD|098|\"welcome \n to the hotel \n california\"\nI|234|\"ya!\"";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\n([IUD])", "_¥$1").replaceAll("\n+"," ").replaceAll("_¥","\n"));
```

Output:

```java
I|123|"hi"
U|321|"ola"
D|098|"welcome   to the hotel   california"
I|234|"ya!"
```

A **general solution** to replace one or more newline chars with a space in between double quotation marks is

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"");
String result = p.matcher(text).replaceAll(x -> x.group().replaceAll("\n+"," "));
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/Ur1xiV):

```java
String s = "I|123|\"hi\"\nU|321|\"ola\"\nD|098|\"welcome \n to the hotel \n california\"\nI|234|\"ya!\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"");
s = p.matcher(s).replaceAll(x -> x.group().replaceAll("\n+"," "));
System.out.println(s);
```

And before Java 9, you can use `Matcher#appendReplacement`:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"");
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result, m.group().replaceAll("\n+", " "));
}
m.appendTail(result);
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/8Go1cu).

Comment: @user15793316 No, it is not correct. The correct regex for that task is `Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"", Pattern.DOTALL)`. Cf. [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rXBHwC/1) with [mine](https://regex101.com/r/rXBHwC/2).

Comment: @user15793316 Another example: [yours](https://regex101.com/r/rXBHwC/3) vs. [mine](https://regex101.com/r/rXBHwC/4).

Comment: Hi Wiktor Stribiżew !  I'm so excited to know that my journey is over! :D !! It worked perfectly!  I could see what was the problem,  basing me on your sample! Thanks so much!